# Making changes to an installed node package?

Tags: javascript, node-modules

I have an external node package installed in my project.  It does 90% of what I want but I'd like to make some changes to it.  I don't want to submit a PR to developer since these changes are unique to my situation and would only be used by me.  What would the best way to go about this?  Inside my `node_modules` folder, the JS file of the library is minified so it's hard to make out anything or edit anything in a coherent manner.

Comment: You can fork the GitHub repository and make your changes locally, then use the repository as a local repository/package/dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be really messing about with the `node_modules` folder, as the code is usually minified (as you have stated).

---

However, the most reasonable approach to do is to follow the steps below.

1. *Fork* the repository on GitHub, and add whatever changes you need to add in the forked repository.
2. If you want, you can make a new `npm` module (if you have an account), and install that in your project.

   Otherwise, you can just add it as a folder in your project, or something like that.

Make sure that this isn't overkill for your project!

---

In conclusion, you shouldn't make changes to the `node_modules` folder, but you can fork the repository as an alternative.